# Sphinx Scope Returning Nothing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, indexing, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I'm trying to create a simple scope that sphinx will index (Ruby on Rails). The normal scope returns what it should, the sphinx scope returns no results.

```
define_index do
  # fields
  indexes :name
  indexes author
  indexes description
  indexes list_of_tags
  indexes approved

  # attributes
  has created_at, updated_at, downloads

  # delta indexing
  set_property :delta => true

  # weighting fields
  set_property :field_weights => {
    :name => 10,
    list_of_tags => 6,
    author => 5,
    description => 4,
  }
```

end

normal scope:

```
scope :approved, where(:approved => true)
```

sphinx scope:

```
sphinx_scope(:approval_scope) {
  {:conditions => {:approved => "true"}}
}
```

Approved is a boolean field, however, since I'm indexing it as a field, I believe its value is treated as a String. Regardless, letting the value of the sphinx scope be "true" or true makes no difference - Theme.approval_score still returns 0 results unlike Theme.approval. I hope I'm missing something simple..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make the approved with has

```
define_index do
  # fields
  ...
  has approved
  ...
end
```

then

```
sphinx_scope(:approval_scope) {
  {:with => {:approved => true}}
}
```

Comment: Almost: use `:approved => true` in your sphinx scope. But yes, you definitely want approved to be an attribute, not a field.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to use :with